# Flutter: Chewie videoplayer video is visible but video's sound is not working while uploading video from IOS device

Tags: ios, flutter, audio, video-player

Flutter Issue is while uploading video from ios device video is visible but the sound is not coming but it is working fine for the Android device. Below code, I used for the video player.

Code:

```
Center(
              child: controller.value.initialized
                  ? Chewie(
                      controller: ChewieController(
                        videoPlayerController: controller,
                        autoPlay: false,
                        aspectRatio: controller.value.aspectRatio,
                        looping: false,
                        showControls: true,
                        // Try playing around with some of these other options:
                        placeholder: Container(
                          child: Center(
                              child: Image.asset("assets/img/mw.png")),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  : new Center(
                      child: new Container(
                      child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    )),
            ),
```